# How to make facebook graph api search case sensitive

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to make graph api search case sensitive ?

for instance:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=%22Salt%20And%20Pepper%22&access_token=2227470867|2.lBGnkrD6uHK_TyFDPp3qVw__.3600.1290103200-2908836|xmhv-FS3f2_GEw6LrGPi70Nbmhs

to not return any "salt and pepper" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no support for case sensitivity.